# NVIDIA problem: nvidia-smi and all other related nvidia commands freeze the terminal

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

I just rebooted a server with 2 nvidia titan X that was perfectly working but now when I type nvidia-smi or start a python process that uses one of the GPUs, the terminal freezes.

Do you have any idea on how to troubleshoot this problem?

Setup:

Ubuntu 14.04 /
cuda 7.5 /
cudnn-7.0

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the issue? I have the same one ([nvidia-smi hangs indefinitely: what could be the issue?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/255658/16704))